# Orfeo tool box (OTB) in Ubuntu 14.04 and SAGA incompatibility (gdal versions)

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, saga, orfeo-toolbox

I need to test segmentation of a 12000 x 12000 pixels scene.
I successfully compiled OTB in Ubuntu 14.04 and ran the process.
But when I tried to start SAGA, I got a startup error.

I found that gdal library in SAGA is version 1.10, but in OTB is 1.11.
After reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 and SAGA with Qgis, system is running, but no segmentation in any one. SAGA exits without error message and Qgis present errors regarding image geographic extension, but is a pancromatic band.

As I see, only OTB runs very well segmentation but I need to see results and extract some polygon statistics with SAGA.
**How can I install both gdal versions in parallel?**

Comment: Any reason you didn't install compatible qgis, otb,  saga and gdal using the UbuntuGIS ppa?

Comment: @Luke I followed documentation for installing otb after qgis and saga. Then the error came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've work with both OTB and SAGA but I would advise on Ubuntu to install both libraries using the ubuntugis-unstable PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/

It should allow you to install last stable release of both otb and saga and also qgis using the same gdal version.

Take care to uninstall previous versions on your system before doing that to avoid package conflicts.

Comment: Resuming installing steps: I was using ** ppa:otb/orfeotoolbox-stable-ubuntugis **
Recomended by (http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/otbqgis.html)
I edited **/etc/apt/sources.list**

Selected the recomended repository
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
sudo apt-get update`

Then I removed qgis
`sudo apt-get autoremove qgis`
And saga too
`sudo apt-get autoremove saga 
Install saga qgis and otb 
sudo apt-get install saga qgis otb-bin otb-bin-qt python-otb`
** (more than 200 Mb to download and install) **

Comment: Now checking if otb have segmentation menu...
... it is fixed now. Everything is running!
Thank you!